# Very slow graphic display refresh after upgrade from Linux Debian Wheezy 7.9 to Jessie 8.6

Tags: debian, nvidia

I upgraded from Debian Wheezy 7.9 to Jessie 8.6. I did a complete reinstall from scratch.
At the end of the install, I followed the recommendations on  page
https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers to recompile the kernel.
There was no problem during the install or the compilation.

The machine is an Asus, with a NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GTX 660M] (rev a1)
graphics card.

Since then, the refresh of the display has slowed down noticeably
compared to what it was before.

For the same LaTeX source text file, the re-display of the PDF output of a compilation, 
which used to be immediate in all cases, now takes quite a bit of time under Okular. The
re-display under Evince also used to be immediate, it is also slower now.

My experience with the NVIDIA GK107M [GeForce GTX 660M] graphics card, under Debian Wheezy 7.9 
and prior to this upgrade, was that it was a very fast card.

Any help on how to recover at least some of the lost performance would
be appreciated. Thanks a lot.